# Any alternative maven glassfish plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, glassfish, unknown-host

Is there an alternative Maven Glassfish Plugin to [this one](https://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/)?

I'm getting an **"UnknownHostException: maven.ocean.net.au"** when running `mvn glassfish:deploy` and I've read on many places on the internet and here on stackoverflow that there is in fact a problem with this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the [maven cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container) which can deploy to multiple application server.

Comment: Excellent, yes, it works with Cargo. I didn't know I could use Cargo for glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [maven-asadmin-plugin](https://github.com/Codeartisans/asadmin) which just works as a wrapper for the asadmin CLI Tool